# On iOS, can we get to the main UIWindow object from the UIScreen object?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiwindow, uiscreen

Say, if we already have `aScreen` that points to the main screen, by

```
UIScreen *aScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
```

can we get to the main `UIWindow` object from this `UIScreen` object? (do they have any connection at all?  That is, instead of using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The application has a list of windows, usually just one. Each window has a `screen` property that indicates where it's currently located. The screen object holds information about the physical device.

It seems inspired on OSX `NSScreen`, there is no a list of windows per screen. Each app has windows, each window knows in which screen is located.

Answer (score 1):

A `UIWindow` knows which screen it's assigned to, but a `UIScreen` doesn't know what `UIWindows` are using it. That's why the standard pattern is to save the main window as a property of the ApplicationDelegate, so you'll have a reference to it.